# The counter starts to increase in decimals when i try to put a variable at its place by php

Tags: javascript, php, html

HTML

```
<div class="counter" data-target="
    <?php
    $sql = "select Books_Not_Returned from booksnotreturned ";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $val = $row['Books_Not_Returned'];
    $Int = (int)$val;
    echo  $Int;
    ?>
    ">0</div>
```

JS

```
  // COUNTER
  const counters = document.querySelectorAll('.counter');
  const speed = 500; // The lower the slower

  counters.forEach(counter => {
  const updateCount = () => {
  const target = +counter.getAttribute('data-target');
  const count = +counter.innerText;

  // Lower inc to slow and higher to slow
  const inc = target / speed;

  // console.log(inc);
  // console.log(count);

  // Check if target is reached
  if (count < target) {
  // Add inc to count and output in counter
  counter.innerText = count + inc;
  // Call function every ms
  setTimeout(updateCount, 1);
  } else {
  counter.innerText = target;
  }
  };

  updateCount();
  });
```

I am trying to make my counter stop at the value which i have stored in database when i tried to assign value of target to that variable it starts as 1.000000000 then 1.10000 and so on up to the actual value of that variable

Comment: So, what is it doing right now instead?

Comment: it starts with double values instead of 0 1 2 3 up to target it increases by 0.00000000 1.00000000 up to target

Answer (score 0):

Actuallly in the js code i am assigning const inct = target/speed ,so inc is assigned with an double to make more delay it have to decrease the inc to decimals i have fixed it by type casting target/speed i,e assigning int to inc